# How to activate shard balancer in sharded MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a very simple MongoDB database structure. Also I have 5 shards in it (3 of them are replicasets). But we are testing DB loading and it seems that shard balancing isn't currently enabled.

On `mongos` I have checked the next:

```
mongos> sh.getBalancerState()
true
mongos> sh.isBalancerRunning()
false
```

I can't set BalancerRunning to true. I tried:

```
sh.startBalancer()
```

Please help me to start it for all my shards. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you have a few misunderstandings here, the first being that the balancer is a load balancer.  It is not - it simply looks to address imbalances in chunk counts on your shards.  That can have the side effect of balancing your traffic out as it moves chunks around, but strictly speaking it is not a load balancer.  It also does not run continuously, rather it runs when there is work to be done and imbalances to address, otherwise it is dormant.

To explain the output you are getting from the commands, let's take them one at a time.  First off, Let's look at what `sh.getBalancerState()` does (run any function without parentheses in the `mongo` shell and you get to see the code behind it):

```
mongos> sh.getBalancerState
function () {
    var x = db.getSisterDB( "config" ).settings.findOne({ _id: "balancer" } )
    if ( x == null )
        return true;
    return ! x.stopped;
}
```

So, what that command is doing is checking the settings collection in the config DB to determine if the balancer is enabled or not.  If we stop the balancer, we see the setting change:

```
mongos> sh.stopBalancer()
Waiting for active hosts...
Waiting for the balancer lock...
Waiting again for active hosts after balancer is off...
mongos> sh.getBalancerState()
false
```

If we flip it back to enabled, we see true returned once more:

```
mongos> sh.startBalancer()
mongos> sh.getBalancerState()
true
```

So, `sh.getBalancerState()` is basically for checking the setting and telling you whether the balancer is enabled or not.  What it does not speak to is whether the balancer is currently actively running (i.e. checking for imbalances, migrating to address any imbalances it finds).  That's where `sh.isBalancerRunning()` comes in.

However, if the balancer is not currently doing any work, it will not be "running" and so it will return false:

```
mongos> sh.isBalancerRunning()
false
```

Hence, let's give it some work to do.  I will re-use my example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19672302/1148648) and create an imbalance while the balancer is off.  Here is `sh.status()` and the output of `sh.getBalancerState()` once I have completed the pre-split:

```
mongos> sh.getBalancerState()
false
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 3,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
    "currentVersion" : 4,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("53b5d3b5d95df3a66a597548")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "localhost:30000" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "localhost:30001" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0002",  "host" : "localhost:30002" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0001" }
    {  "_id" : "users",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0001" }
        users.userInfo
            shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
            chunks:
                shard0001   2049
            too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
```

Once I re-enable the balancer, it is going to have plenty of work to do to redistribute those 2049 (empty) chunks evenly across 3 shards, so I will have plenty of opportunity to run `sh.isBalancerRunning()` and get a positive.  Interestingly, it took me several tries to get this to return true (just showing two for brevity):

```
mongos> sh.isBalancerRunning()
false
mongos> sh.isBalancerRunning()
true
```

Why is that? Well, let's look at the function again:

```
mongos> sh.isBalancerRunning
function () {
    var x = db.getSisterDB("config").locks.findOne({ _id: "balancer" });
    if (x == null) {
        print("config.locks collection empty or missing. be sure you are connected to a mongos");
        return false;
    }
    return x.state > 0;
}
```

It is a query on the config database again, this time on the locks collection.  It looks for a lock belonging to the balancer and then returns true if the state is greater than 0.  Here are two examples of the document, one that returns false and one that returns true:

```
db.getSisterDB("config").locks.findOne({ _id: "balancer" });
{
    "_id" : "balancer",
    "process" : "adamc-mbp:30999:1404425140:16807",
    "state" : 2,
    "ts" : ObjectId("53b5d86fd95df3a66a5975ff"),
    "when" : ISODate("2014-07-03T22:25:51.574Z"),
    "who" : "adamc-mbp:30999:1404425140:16807:Balancer:1622650073",
    "why" : "doing balance round"
}
db.getSisterDB("config").locks.findOne({ _id: "balancer" });
{
    "_id" : "balancer",
    "process" : "adamc-mbp:30999:1404425140:16807",
    "state" : 0,
    "ts" : ObjectId("53b5d86ed95df3a66a5975fe"),
    "when" : ISODate("2014-07-03T22:25:50.528Z"),
    "who" : "adamc-mbp:30999:1404425140:16807:Balancer:1622650073",
    "why" : "doing balance round"
}
```

If you look closely, you will notice that the `ts` fields are essentially consecutive, and what you will see with empty chunks is that the non-zero states are very transient.  If I fill up the chunks with data it is far easier to generate a positive.

There you have it - a full explanation of the commands you were running and why you got the results you saw.  I suspect that the root of the question is actually related to a traffic imbalance, but it is not the balancer that generally causes that type of problem (as mentioned before, it is not a load balancer) - traffic imbalance is more likely cause by:

- A poor shard key (perhaps very poor)
- Balancing is not enabled for the database/collection (see previous pre-split answer for instructions there)
- Something is preventing the balancer from working (config server down, balancer window, migration aborts)

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. I want to remind, I'm not developer so these parts of codes are very far for me. Anyway, but I have been chosen to install Ubuntu servers, deploy security and MongoDB on them. Can you please tell me exactly what should I do the next? What should I check? I had read mongodb official manuals regarding to the shared key and it is rather for developers than for sysadmins. I don't want corrupt exsisting databases.

Comment: Configuration was performed according to the next manual: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sharded-cluster-in-mongodb-using-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps
I'm writing here because I'm completely confused.
Thank you.

Comment: The questions you are asking are essentially how to run and operate MongoDB properly, and that is beyond the scope of the comments here.  I would recommend you look at the (free) courses at https://university.mongodb.com - the M202 course covers a lot of your questions (fair disclosure - I wrote and recorded that course) and takes 7 weeks to complete (next run starts July 15th).  I would also recommend the official docs such as these tutorials on security http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/

Comment: I'm interested in your cources but I need to show some results to my boss. At this point I need to make sharding workable. At this stage I'm confused in the next. As I said before I have 5 shards and I have 3 databases. When are doing inserts I see heavy loading only on first shard.Just to clarify.After the cluster was deployed we just created the database (no else actions were performed e.g. sh.enableSharding("test_db") etc.). Then database was uploaded. That's all. It seem I had missed something. I think I'll need enable sharding once satabase will be created.

Comment: Can you just describe step-by-step in a few words an easiest way of new database creation in existing MongoDB cluster from new database creation to its correct uploading, so it will be partitioned between all shards in our cluster? e.g. we have database "test_db" with collections "apple, orange,pepper, salt". To clarify, I didn't performed Enable Sharding on the Collections Level previously as it has been mentioned in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sharded-cluster-in-mongodb-using-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps. Thank you very much.

Comment: I linked to the answer which has step by step instructions to get to a sharded collection - literally, you can paste them in.  If you don't enable sharding, then all databases and collections will remain on a single shard and will not be balanced, so that is a required step.  Again, I would recommend reading the documentation on sharding so you understand what you are actually doing, then if something does not work, ask that as a question.  Given that your requirements are pretty simple though, if you perform the needed steps I don't think you will have any problems

Comment: Awesome. I had followed with [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19672302/1148648) instruction and it helps me to re-create my databases with sharding enabled. As I see, all my servers are taking a part in sharding process. But as I see one of my servers has heavy loading. Please check [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ay0sjj4o3pv3ed/shot_140707_113717.jpg).
Is there any way to investigate this issue and decrease overloading? All my servers have the same configuration.

Comment: Usually hotspots are caused by a poor shard key - I would recommend asking a new question that includes the relevant details about how you are sharding, the comments are not meant for extensive troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB Docs:](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.setBalancerState/)

> Enables or disables the balancer. Use sh.getBalancerState() to determine if the balancer is currently enabled or disabled and sh.isBalancerRunning() to check its current state.

Sharded Collection Balancing:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-balancing/

But your question should go in [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I said, I'm new in MongoDB so can you just let me know how to correctly enable sharding? Should I enable it for specific database etc? As you can see from my first post, I had already executed `sh.getBalancerState()`

Comment: No problem man :D, first for all: Do you tried to deploy? sometimes is required.

Comment: This is what I did. I had deployed cluster with: 4 config, 3 query, 9 shards according to the next manual: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/
All nodes are visible and is seems everything is working :)

Comment: But I had database test_db. And I want to enable sharding for it. This is what I had done:
1. I had connecetd from shared shell to mongos via mongo --host query1.server.com --port 27017
2. sh.enableSharding("test_db")
3. db.databases.find( { "partitioned": true } )
mongos> db.databases.find()
{ "_id" : "admin", "partitioned" : false, "primary" : "config" }
{ "_id" : "test_db", "partitioned" : false, "primary" : "shard0000" }
{ "_id" : "db", "partitioned" : false, "primary" : "shard0001" }

Comment: Seems that sharding\balancing should be enabled. But im monitoring inserts (this is my general task) and I see no loading on my other shards. Oly one (first shard) shard loaded. How can I share test_db betwen several my shards?